# Getting undefined values when adding a table data using vue js and laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, vue.js, vue-resource

I have this project that when a user clicks on a button the data should be displayed on a table. However, I am using a table as seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW4rE.jpg. What I want is that when a user clicks on the add button on the enrollment form table, it should displayed on the added subjects table without the need of refreshing the page. The problem is that I am using a table and I cannot make use of the v-model to bind the values.

So here's my form.blade.php

Enrollment Form table

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Subject Code</th>
    <th>Descriptive Title</th>
    <th>Schedule</th>
    <th>No. of Units</th>
    <th>Room</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <body>
    <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="{{ $student_id }}">
    @foreach($subjects as $subject)
      @foreach($subject->sections as $section)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $section->section_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ $subject->subject_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ $subject->subject_description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $section->pivot->schedule }}</td>
        <td>{{ $subject->units }}</td>
        <td>{{ $section->pivot->room_no }}</td>
        <td>
          <button 
              v-on:click="addSubject( {{ $section->pivot->id}}, {{ $student_id}} )" 
              class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Add
          </button>

          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    @endforeach
  </body>
</table>
```

AddedSubjects Table

```
<table class="table table-bordered">     
    <tr>
      <th>Section Code</th>
      <th>Subject Code</th>
      <th>Descriptive Title</th>
      <th>Schedule</th>
      <th>No. of Units</th>
      <th>Room</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    <body>

    <tr v-for="reservation in reservations">
      <td>@{{ reservation.section.section_code }}</td>
      <td>@{{ reservation.subject.subject_code }}</td>
      <td>@{{ reservation.subject.subject_description }}</td>
      <td>@{{ reservation.schedule }}</td>
      <td>@{{ reservation.subject.units }}</td>
      <td>@{{ reservation.room_no }}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    </body>
</table>
```

And here's my all.js

```
new Vue({
el: '#app-layout',

data: {

    reservations: []

},
ready: function(){
    this.fetchSubjects();
},
methods:{

    fetchSubjects: function(){
        this.$http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/reservation',
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function (reservations){
            this.$set('reservations', reservations.data);
            console.log('success');
        }, function (response){
            console.log('failed');
        });
    },

    addSubject: function(section,subject,student_id){
        var self = this;
        this.$http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/reservation',   
            data: { sectionSubjectId: section.pivot.id, studentId: student_id },
            method: 'POST'
        }).then(function(response) {
            self.$set('reservations', response.data);   
            console.log(response);
            self.reservations.push(response.data);
        },function (response){
            console.log('failed');
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Here's my ReservationController

```
class ReservationController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    $student = Student::with(['sectionSubjects','sectionSubjects.section', 'sectionSubjects.subject'])->find(1);

    return $student->sectionSubjects;    

}

public function create($id)
{
    $student_id = $id;

    $subjects = Subject::with('sections')->get();

    return view('reservation.form',compact('subjects','student_id'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

    $subject = SectionSubject::findOrFail($request->sectionSubjectId);

    $student = Student::with(['sectionSubjects','sectionSubjects.section', 'sectionSubjects.subject'])->findOrFail($request->studentId);

    $subject->assignStudents($student);

    return $student->sectionSubjects;

   }
}
```

Can anyone suggets me on how to solve this problem, without the need of refreshing the page.

By the way I have this errors in my console.log

```
Error when evaluating expression "reservation.section.section_code": TypeError: Cannot read property 'section_code' of undefined

Error when evaluating expression "reservation.subject.subject_code": TypeError: Cannot read property 'subject_code' of undefined

Error when evaluating expression "reservation.subject.subject_description": TypeError: Cannot read property     'subject_description' of undefined

Error when evaluating expression "reservation.subject.units": TypeError: Cannot read property 'units' of undefined
```

Comment: Please include the actual error message and where it is happening.

Comment: @LinusBorg Kindly see updated code. Thank you.

Comment: @Linus Borg I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use vue-devtools to inspect what data is actually inside `reservations` after it was fetched from the server.

Because the error message simply means that the objects in this array do not have a `.subject` property, which means the data you receive probably does not have the structure you assume it to have, and that is where your solutiuon will be found.

I don't know much PHP or Laravel, but it seems that your GET request gets its response form the index method, and this method seems to reply with an array of subjects, not an array of reservations (which should contain the subjects, according to your template code)

Comment: Okay I used vue-devtools and I got this result. http://imgur.com/FUxWd2f It turns out that when pushing the response.data to reservations the format is array. As you can see in the link, the 2:Array is not an object. How can I solved this now?